# How can I conform to StringProtocol in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want make a struct called **CustomStruct**, which would conform to **StringProtocol**, I started implementing the condition that needed, and I done half of that, need help to understand rest and complete the rest, thanks.

```
struct CustomStruct: StringProtocol {

    var value: String  // <<: this is my value!
    
    

    typealias UTF8View = <#type#>    // <<: Need help! 
    
    typealias UTF16View = <#type#>    // <<: Need help! 
    
    typealias UnicodeScalarView = <#type#>     // <<: Need help! 
    
    
    mutating func write(_ string: String) {
        value = string    // <<: Done!
    }
    
    func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream {
        <#code#>    // <<: Need help! 
    }
    
    var startIndex: String.Index { return value.startIndex }    // <<: Done!
    
    var endIndex: String.Index { return value.endIndex }    // <<: Done!
    
    var description: String { return value }    // <<: Done!

}
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol)? It literally says "Do not declare new conformances to `StringProtocol`." Why would you want to conform to `StringProtocol`?

Comment: that was my first place look, I could not help myself.

Comment: I don't understand. You could not help yourself to conform to `StringProtocol`? What makes you want to conform to it so badly?

Comment: I mean that Link was my first search in internet and that was not helpful for my to solve the problem, i like understand it! for example I know when we need **description**, but why **typealias UTF8View**, typealias has nothing to do after defining in my struc, why I need those at first place?

Comment: Now that's a slightly more useful question. You need those type alias because they are required by the protocol.

Comment: Here's a [paste](https://pastebin.com/gYVitWj6) that shows how you can possibly do this. It compiles, but I doubt the runtime would like it, since the docs *explicitly said* not to conform to `StringProtocol`. I hope you can learn something about delegating conformance to protocols from this, _just not to `StringProtocol`_.

Comment: This question is peak SO. I love how OP still hasn't explained the fervent need to implement `StringProtocol`, or how an implementation that simply wraps `String` is useful.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez: because I have only 1 account for my both questions and answers.

Comment: I think the real issue here, is that @ioscoder ran into a problem and _thinks_ that conforming to `StringProtocol` is the solution.  It is not the solution, but we don't know the original problem.  I can guess.  I ran into a similar problem and this question/answer helped solve it.  So even poor questions are useful :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) clearly says

> Do not declare new conformances to `StringProtocol`. Only the `String` and `Substring` types in the standard library are valid conforming types.

You SHOULD NOT conform to `StringProtocol`.

---

But let's say you are learning about how to conform to protocols, and just happened to choose `StringProtocol` to practice (which is a really bad thing to do, I repeat).

It seems like you want to conform to it by delegating all the requirements to the string `value`. First, you have not specified all its requirements. You still need:

- `init(_:)`
- `init(stringLiteral:)`
- `uppercased`
- `lowercased`
- `utf8`
- `utf16`
- `unicodeScalars`
- `init(decoding:as:)`
- `init(decodingCString:as:)`
- `init(cString:)`
- `withCString(_:)`
- `withCString(encodedAs:_:)`
- `index(before:)`
- `index(after:)`
- `subscript(_:)`

You can find all the requirements in the documentation.

I am not sure why you are stuck on implementing `write(to:)`:

```
func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream {
    value.write(to: &target)
}
```

You also implemented `write(_:)` incorrectly. `write(_:)` is supposed to *append* to the receiver, not replace the `value` with the parameter entirely. But again, the *correct* thing to do here is not to conform to `StringProtocol` at all...

> for example I know when we need description, but why typealias UTF8View, typealias has nothing to do after defining in my struc, why I need those at first place?

Those actually determine the types of the properties `utf8`, `utf16` and `unicodeScalar`, which are three of the requirements you missed. If you declare those properties, you don't need the type aliases.