# Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'OneCall.HourlyResponse' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Tags: swiftui

I have an iOS SwiftUI OpenWeatherMap App using the OneCall API 1.0. I get an error that says `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'OneCall.HourlyResponse' conform to 'StringProtocol'`.
Here is my code which might be related to the error:

Main WeatherView file:

```swift
ScrollView(.horizontal){
    HStack(spacing: 5.0) {
        ForEach(0..<25) {_ in
            VStack{
                Text(weather.hourly) //Line with error
                    .bold()
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .frame(width: 105, height: 15)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ResponseBody:

```swift
struct OneCall: Decodable{
    let lat, lon: Double
    let timezone : String
    let timezone_offset : Int
    let current: CurrentResponse
    let hourly: HourlyResponse

    struct HourlyResponse: Decodable{
        var hourly = ""
    }
}
```

In the OneCall struct, I have many more structs inside but I only included the HourlyResponse struct.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I conform to StringProtocol in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66762971/how-can-i-conform-to-stringprotocol-in-swift)

Comment: @Desdenova this doesn't really answer my question. I know I should not conform to StringProtocol.

Comment: I think you are using the struct instead of it's string field. What is `weather.hourly`

Comment: @Desdenova I've updated the question for `weather.hourly`

Comment: Use `weather.hourly.hourly`

Comment: OK wait... It worked!

Comment: @Desdenova You can post an answer to mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `weather` instance is of type `OneCall`.

When you use `weather.hourly`, it is of type `OneCall.HourlyResponse`, which is obviously doesn't conform to `StringProtocol`.

`weather.hourly.hourly` is your string property which you need to use.